# Is there a characterization for compact and orientable hypersurfaces with positive sectional curvature?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I know that a compact surface $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ of positive Gaussian curvature is homeomorphic to a sphere from Gauss-Bonnet's theorem. This led me to ask if there is a characterization for compact and orientable hypersurfaces with positive sectional curvature with possibly some additional hypothesis. I think maybe need some additional hypothesis because if there was a characterization without more hypothesis, then the [Hopf's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_conjecture#Product_conjecture_for_the_product_of_two_spheres) would be solved.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "hypersurface"?

Comment: A Riemannian manifold immersed in another Riemannian manifold such that the codimension is $1$.

Comment: Isometrically immersed, or just immersed? Regardless, in dimension $\ge 3$ there are lots of nonhomeomorphic compact orientable manifolds of positive sectional curvature, so you won't be able to get anything as nice as the 2-dimensional result.

Comment: Isometrically immersed. Do you have a reference for the case when dimension $\geq 3$?

Comment: You might want to look into [Lens spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_space) and [spherical 3-manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_3-manifold), which inherit orientations and metrics of constant positive sectional curvature from $S^3$. Similar examples exist in higher dimensions, and all of these can appear as immersed hypersurfaces of suitable ambient manifolds.